# Javascript Unable to validate computed reference to imported namespace

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

Not sure if I need to add another jshint library or if I should do this a different way.

I have a file (for explanations reasons we'll call it stuff-functions.js) that exports functions like this...

```
export function a() {
    return 'stuff';
}

export function b() {
    return 'more stuff';
}

export function c() {
    return 'even more stuff';
}
```

In another file I'm importing that file and calling that function by an argument...

```
import * as stuffFunctions from './stuff-functions'

export default class someReactClass {
    myFunc(functionToCall) {
        return stuffFunctions[functionToCall]();
    }
    ...
}
```

It works fine, but in the console I'm getting an eslint error...

```
Unable to validate computed reference to imported namespace 'stuffFunctions'
```

So, should I go about this differently or hunt down some sort of eslint library that allows for this?

EDIT...

I've added this line to stop the error // eslint-disable-line

I was just curious if there was a better way to do this. Maybe something like...

```
import {a, b, c} from './stuff-functions';

export default class someReactClass {
    myFunc(functionToCall) {
        const myStuffFunctions = {
            a: a,
            b: b,
            c: c
        };

        return myStuffFunctions[functionToCall]();
    }
    ...
}
```

Seems redundant though. :/

Comment: Personally, I think eslint does a better job in dealing with es6 and react(jsx). I use eslint + jsbeautifier.

Comment: My bad, it is an eslint error, not jshint.

Comment: Do you know what rule is flagging that then?

Comment: looks like it comes from this es-lint plugin. https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import. As far as I can tell your code should be valid as long as your transpiler can import `* as`.

Answer (score 22):

The error is being reported by the `import/namespace` rule in the [eslint-plugin-import](http://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import) plugin. It's occurring because you are deciding which imported function will be called at runtime:

```
stuffFunctions[functionToCall]();
```

The plugin's static analysis cannot verify that this is a valid import and it reports it as an error.

The simplest solution would be to add an ESLint comment to reconfigure the rule to [allow computed references](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/namespace.md#allowcomputed):

```
/*eslint import/namespace: ['error', { allowComputed: true }]*/
import * as stuffFunctions from './stuff-functions'

export default class someReactClass {
    myFunc(functionToCall) {
        return stuffFunctions[functionToCall]();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cartant. I edited my original question with what I did and another thought of going about it. I just figured if I'm getting that kind of error, it's probably a bad thing and maybe should do something about it. Everything is working just fine the way I have it coded so maybe suppressing the eslint error is the thing to do in this case.

Comment: @BruceSmith, you really ought to select this as the accepted answer.